# Kronecker Product for arbitrary number of spins

Tags: function-construction, products

I want to write a function that can perform the following kronecker product:

```
sx = PauliMatrix[1];
id = IdentityMatrix[2];
I1x = KroneckerProduct[sx, id, id];
I2x = KroneckerProduct[id, sx, id];
I3x = KroneckerProduct[id, id, sx];
```

This code works for 3 spins.
However, I would like to write a general function which can return I1x and other operators (for Iy is the same but with sy=PauliMatrix[2] etc) for an arbitrary number of spins.

Comment: A starting point could be: `With[{nspin = 3, pos = 2},
 Apply[KroneckerProduct, 
  ReplacePart[ConstantArray[id, {nspin}], pos -> sx]]
 ]`.

Comment: That's really great, thank you. I will try to extend it to system with spin>1/2 for which sx will be different.